# How to Hide VSCode Titlebar

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I want to hide the vscode title bar, which contain menus..etc in windows os. 
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Press F11, It will hide the title bar. It should work on every editor.

Comment: That's right, but I want to even show the Window Taskbar.

Answer (score -2):

Go through File → Preferences → Settings and search up Window: Title Bar Style. Set it to custom.

Comment: "window.titleBarStyle": "custom" still active on there!